# How to return JSON instead of Case Class in akka-Http

Tags: json, scala, akka-stream, akka-http

I created a route to stream a list of case class in JSON. But if I use ByteString, the case class is printed instead of JSON

```
def streamRoute: Route = pathEndOrSingleSlash {
        val byteString = new LocalFileParser(config).importFromFiles.map(phoneNumber => ByteString(phoneNumber.toString + "\n"))
        complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, byteString))
    }
   // RESULT: PhoneNumber(+35799000123,Some(357),Some(Cyprus),Some(Cytamobile-Vodafone),Some(MOBILE))
```

If I just use `complete(new LocalFileParser(config).importFromFiles)`, then this is giving me JSON. Is the second method good for streaming chunked response? If no, How can I fix first method to return JSON instead of Case Class

Comment: Why can’t you just convert your case class into JSON?

Answer (score 0):

With the `Json.toJson(result)` method you can send your result as a JSON,

In your case something like this : `val byteString = new LocalFileParser(config).importFromFiles.map(phoneNumber => Ok(Json.toJson(phoneNumber)))`

Hope this helps

PS: Ok is probably the HTTP code you want to send there

Answer (score 0):

Considering you're already using Circe, you can simplify by adding this library into your project:

```scala
"de.heikoseeberger" %% "akka-http-circe" % "<latest-version>"
```

and importing these two classes in order to marshal your `List[PhoneNumber]` to an `HttpResponse` containing json:

```scala
import de.heikoseeberger.akkahttpcirce.ErrorAccumulatingCirceSupport._
import io.circe.generic.auto._

def streamRoute: Route = pathEndOrSingleSlash {
  complete(new LocalFileParser(config).importFromFiles)
}
```